# Invalid Spring Config Server Configuration (Vault as Backend)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hashicorp-vault

I want to create a config server with vault backend and followed these steps:

1. install vault
2. create and run server using:

```
storage "raft" {
  path    = "./vault/data"
  node_id = "node1"
}

listener "tcp" {
  address     = "127.0.0.1:8200"
  tls_disable = "true"
}

api_addr = "http://127.0.0.1:8200"
cluster_addr = "https://127.0.0.1:8201"
ui = true
```

3. check server status

```
Key                     Value
---                     -----
Seal Type               shamir
Initialized             true
Sealed                  false
Total Shares            5
Threshold               3
Version                 1.14.1
Build Date              2023-07-21T10:15:14Z
Storage Type            raft
Cluster Name            vault-cluster-d9454c69
Cluster ID              36c8d03f-522d-d9e9-4ae4-cceea7074298
HA Enabled              true
HA Cluster              https://127.0.0.1:8201
HA Mode                 active
Active Since            2023-08-08T09:12:40.45953Z
Raft Committed Index    40
Raft Applied Index      40
```

Vault is unsealed previously by cli commands.

4. Setup Spring Configuration

```yaml
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        vault:
          host: localhost
          port: 8200
          scheme: https
          backend: kv
          token: <<added token from vault operator init command>>
```

5. Spring Apllication

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class CloudConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CloudConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

when i try to run this:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Invalid config server configuration.

Action:

If you are using the git profile, you need to set a Git URI in your configuration.  If you have set spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true, you need to use a composite configuration.
```

tried different things and resources but couldnt find a solution for this one. Anyone can help to identify what is the problem?

**UPDATE**

I changed scheme to http and ran the server

```yaml
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        vault:
          host: localhost
          port: 8200
          scheme: http
          backend: kv
          token: <<added token from vault operator init command>>
```

still same error showing. Feels like spring fails before attempt to connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the `vault` profile.

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  profiles:
    active: vault
  application:
    name: config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        vault:
          host: localhost
          port: 8200
          scheme: http
          backend: kv
          authentication: TOKEN
          kv-version: 2
          token: <<root token>>
```

Regarding kv version, kv version 2 adds `/data` path to its API. It seems every example in the pattern of `vault kv put secret/application foo=bar baz=bam` in the internet doesn't work. Following rest api calls creates key values in `config-server` path for v2 API.

create data

```
curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/kv/data/config-server' \
--header 'X-Vault-Token: <<vault root token>>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"data":{"foo":"baz"}}'
```

get data

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8200/v1/kv/data/config-server' \
--header 'X-Vault-Token: <<vault root token>>'
```

check via spring config server

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8888/config-server/default' \
--header 'X-Config-Token: <<vault root token>>'
```

Please note that application name used here is `config-server`. Also v1 type seems to be working with the examples in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/current/reference/html/#vault-backend).

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation:

- https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/reference/html/

You're indicating the configuration under

```
spring.application.cloud.config.server.vault
```

But it should be under:

```
spring.cloud.vault
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Spring configuration specifies the Vault backend as "kv," but your Vault configuration example uses the "raft" storage backend. Make sure you're using the correct Vault storage backend and adjust your Spring configuration accordingly.